# Can not get highchart to display on page - only example will display

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

listed below are 2 blocks of code, the first is my page with a stock example, which works. The 2nd group is a graph I created in jfiddle. It works correctly in jfiddle but when put into the page it does not display anything on the page. Thanks for the help, I am new to jquery and highcharts but I can't seem to find why the below works in jfiddle and not on my page. Thank you.

This below block works, example - but page set up is the same for the block that doesn't work (at bottom)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'gauge',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBackgroundImage: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: 0,
                        plotShadow: false
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'Speedometer'
                    },

                    pane: {
                        startAngle: -150,
                        endAngle: 150,
                        background: [{
                            backgroundColor: {
                                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                                stops: [
                        [0, '#FFF'],
                        [1, '#333']
                    ]
                            },
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            outerRadius: '109%'
                        }, {
                            backgroundColor: {
                                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                                stops: [
                        [0, '#333'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                            },
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            outerRadius: '107%'
                        }, {
                        // default background
                    }, {
                        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        outerRadius: '105%',
                        innerRadius: '103%'
                    }]
                },

                // the value axis
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 200,

                    minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                    minorTickWidth: 1,
                    minorTickLength: 10,
                    minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                    minorTickColor: '#666',

                    tickPixelInterval: 30,
                    tickWidth: 2,
                    tickPosition: 'inside',
                    tickLength: 10,
                    tickColor: '#666',
                    labels: {
                        step: 2,
                        rotation: 'auto'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'km/h'
                    },
                    plotBands: [{
                        from: 0,
                        to: 120,
                        color: '#55BF3B' // green
                    }, {
                        from: 120,
                        to: 160,
                        color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
                    }, {
                        from: 160,
                        to: 200,
                        color: '#DF5353' // red
                    }]
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Speed',
                    data: [80],
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
                    }
                }]

            },
            // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    });
                    });

​
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="./include/Highcharts-2.3.2/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="./include/Highcharts-2.3.2/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="./include/Highcharts-2.3.2/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

code from my graph that does not display

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            height: 200

        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        pane: [{
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: null,
            center: ['50%', '50%'],
            size: 100
        }],                        

        yAxis: [{
            tickInterval: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 180,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
                rotation: 'auto',
                distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 45,
                color: '#00CC00',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            },{
                from: 46,
                to: 90,
                color: '#FFFF00',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            },{
                from: 91,
                to: 135,
                color: '#FF9933',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            },{
                from: 136,
                to: 180,
                color: '#990000',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 0,
            title: {
                text: '<span style="font-size:8px"> </span>',
                y: -40
            }
        }],

        plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%'
                }
            }
        },


        series: [{
            data: [90],
            yAxis: 0
        }]

    },

    // Let the music play
    function(chart) {
        setInterval(function() {
            chart.redraw();
        }, 500);

    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="./include/Highcharts-2.3.2/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="./include/Highcharts-2.3.2/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="./include/Highcharts-2.3.2/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually yes, sorry for not checking before - HighChartsTest.aspx, line 105 character 3 - it apears to be at the blank line before </script> but I can't seem to tell what is missing.

Comment: I found what the issue was, answer will be posted below

Comment: console always helps :)
But now your question becomes totally invalid ;) as it won't help anyone because of being a localized issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue, copied the text out of visual studio and pasted into notepad, which showed a random question mark before the end of script that is not there in visual studio or jfiddle as well as when copied from visual studio to this window. Deleted, recopied text and pasted. At least it now works.